# Why does it give that result?

Tags: javascript, console

It gives two different outputs, any explanation why this is happening?

I need it for an if statement, it gives a true as a result while the statement isn't true (as I think)

```js
var input = prompt("Enter a string to check whether it is a Prime String or not");
function isPrime(str, d){
    var arr = Array.from(str);
    var len = arr.length ;
    //DeBugging   beg
    // arr equals to jkjkjk
    console.log(arr, arr.reverse());
    console.log(arr.reverse());
    console.log( arr == arr.reverse());
    //DeBugging   end
    if(arr == arr.reverse()){
        return true;
    }else{
        var arr2 = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < len ; i + d){
            arr2.push(arr.slice(i, i+d));
        }
        console.log(arr2); 
    }
}
isPrime(input,2);
```

Comment: Please add the code to your post.

Comment: Please post the code (as a [mcve]), not a link to a painting.

Comment: @Bergi actually... a painting would be pretty cool.

Comment: ["The reverse() method reverses an array in place."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) - the "in place" is the important part.

Comment: Sorry guys Im new here, I'll edit it in a sec. :)

Comment: @JordanS Sure, but still fail the requirements of SO :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse), the `reverse` method changes the order of the values contained in an array, but the array is still the same, it is just mutated.

Comment: But I'm not comparing with the same array (...... == arr), I'm comparing with the inverse of it (....... ==arr.reverse()).

Comment: @BRKOTTA `let a = [1], b = a; b[0] = 2; console.log(a === b);` - maybe this example will help you.

Comment: Does that happen because of the b = a ?

Comment: Does it mean that a will always be the same as b throughout the entire program?

Comment: `b` and `a` are just references to the same array in that example. Same for your reversed array. You can also try this: `let a = [1, 2], b = a.reverse(); console.log(a);`

Comment: It's clear now that arr is the same as arr.reverse() because whenever .reverse() is called for an array it will change the whole thing and will change all the variables in the program, even if variables came before the .reverse() line.                                                                 Is that correct?